# CakePHP REST custom routes for parameters

Tags: cakephp, routes

I'm playing around with REST in CakePHP (2.0).  I'm able to return XML data using /news/articles.xml, but i want to filter these results using paginate.

I want to use cake's standard format for GET vars e.g. articles/page:2/limit:3, but not having much luck.  When i try articles.xml/page:2, cake looks for the controller articles.xml.  Using standard GET vars format e.g. articles?page=2&limit=3 works fine using: `$this->request->query`  I'd prefer to use `$this->passedArgs` if possible.

Should this work, or do i need to do some custom routing.  If i can omit the extension, i think this would help, but when i've tried:

```
Router::connect('/articles/*', array('controller' => 'news', 
                                     'action' => 'articles',
                                     'url' => array('ext' => 'xml')));
```

I just get the default html output.

Cheers

Ross

Comment: Doesnt your route need a wildcard in there somewhere? eg, '/articles/*'

Comment: Sorry yes, i've amended my post.  The problem still exists with the wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

The extension should come *after* the url, so it would be something like `/articles/page:2.xml`.